# Using C# generics for specific type support without hardcoding type comparision

Tags: c#, generics, polymorphism

I have function which takes in a serialized string, breaks the string apart to build however many objects it defines, and then returns a generic list. Here is the function and it is working exactly as I need it to:

```
// 'T' only supports specific types - those derived from BaseObject.
internal static T[] DeserializeData<T>(string serializedData)
{
    var data = new List<T>();

    // Break into individual serialized items and decode each.
    foreach (var serializedItem in (serializedData ?? "").Split(','))
    {
        // Skip empty entries.
        if (serializedItem == "")
        {
            continue;
        }

        // Base class which 'T' will always be derived from.
        BaseObject item = null;

        // Initialize object based on the generic type provided.
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(BaseObjectSpecific1))
        {
            item = new BaseObjectSpecific1();
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(BaseObjectSpecific2))
        {
            item = new BaseObjectSpecific2();
        }
        // Add additional checks for BaseObjectSpecific3, etc.


        item.BuildFromSerializedValue(serializedItem);

        data.Add((T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T)));
    }

    return data.ToArray();
}
```

For lack of better words, I'm trying to do some "reverse polymorphism" without explicitly comparing each supported type 'T'. For example, I would like to do this instead of the `if`, `else if`, `...`:

```
// Create a new object and then convert it to the generic type T.
// Then cast it back to the base object so we can access the deserialize method.
var item = (BaseObject)Convert.ChangeType(new BaseObject(), typeof(T));
item.BuildFromSerializedValue(serializedItem);

data.Add((T)Convert.ChangeType(item, typeof(T)));
```

Of course this does not work because a new `BaseObject` cannot be cast "forward" to an inherited class.

I have tried having the function return an array of `BaseObject`s:

```
internal static BaseObject[] DeserializeData(string serializedData)
```

But this doesn't work when I am merging the return value into a `List<BaseObjectSpecific1>` (etc.)

I feel like am I missing something or making this more complicated than required. Is there a way I can support any type of `BaseObject` using generics without having to explicitly compare T to each inherited class type?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use [Generics Constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) along with the `new()` constraint:

```
internal static T[] DeserializeData<T>(string serializedData)
     where T : BaseObject, new()
{
    var data = new List<T>();

    // Break into individual serialized items and decode each.
    foreach (var serializedItem in (serializedData ?? "").Split(','))
    {
        // Skip empty entries.
        if (serializedItem == "")
            continue;

        T item = new T();

        // Add additional checks for BaseObjectSpecific3, etc.

        item.BuildFromSerializedValue(serializedItem);

        data.Add(item);
    }

    return data.ToArray();
}
```

This way, the compiler already knows that each `T` is deriving from `BaseObject` (hence having the `BuildFromSerializedValue()` method). And, by using the `new()` constraint it also knows that it's possible to create new instances of `T` because it's having a parameter-less constructor.

Also, you no longer need to explicitly cast `item` to `T` since the compiler already knows *it is* a `T`.

More on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sd2w2ew5.aspx)

Comment: Perfect. I knew I was missing something simple. Thank you for your help with this.